# Why is the sharepoint system account in my root site permissions?

Tags: search

I have a 2010 Standard Farm.  Over the last few months of setting up our new intranet, lots of accounts were added to the root site permissions.  Most of our site collections inherited those accounts, including "SHAREPOINT\System".  It was deleted without fully understanding why it was there.  Since then, I reset the search index.  Now I can't get it to crawl any of our sites.  Was this account added to the root site collection so it can read in the sites?  Is it as simple as adding it back in?  Or is this issue completely unrelated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search crawl account should be given special read permissions via web application policy in Central Administration, not by having an entry in the site.  It should also not be the System account as using that account to index your site will include a lot of noise in the results.  Adding the Web Application Policy is normally handled automatically when the crawl account is defined but it is possible that it was deleted so check there first to make sure it still has read permission to that web application.

The next step is to make sure that the content source in the Search Service application is configured properly to either include all local sites or include your site by URL.  It is also a good idea to make sure that your Alternate Access Mappings are configured properly.

If any of the above was out of order, correct that, reset your search index and kick off a full crawl.

To answer your original question though, in a properly configured farm there is no reason why the SharePoint\System account should ever appear in a site collection's permissions.

Comment: Ok, it seems that removing that account was not the problem.  I checked the crawl account and it is set to full read only.  I summary, I'm pretty sure my content source and access mappings are correct.  And I did reset the index and kicked off a full crawl.  But I'm still not getting any results.

Comment: If the crawl still isn't happening, I'd look at the errors in the Crawl Log for the appropriate content source.  It is also possible that you have an overly aggressive Crawl Rule defined that may be excluding much more than it should.

Comment: I checked the crawl log, it reads "The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service. ( Error from SharePoint site )".  In the event viewer on the server, I see the error "The start address http://sharepointserver cannot be crawled."  The account listed is the same one in the crawler service.  But still I cannot get my content indexed.

Comment: Thanks.  My crawl rule reads "http://sharepointserver/*".  If I copy and paste the root page in my browser, the test shows successful.

Comment: If you open a browser window on the SharePoint server itself and then attempt to access the URL to your sharepoint site (in that browser window), what happens?

Comment: The site displays correctly and I can move about.  Everything was working fine until I rebooted the server.  I've been scratching my head for days now trying to figure out why it's not indexing.  When I review my recent changes, this was one and it got me wondering if it was causing the site to not respond.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to either log onto the server as the crawl account or start a new browser instance as the crawl account (shift-right-click trick) and try to navigate the site that way.  If there are any security issues in the middle, that would expose them